# Who uses the term 'freehold'?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, american-english, subcontinental-english, australian-english

I am interested to discover in which countries, where English is used, the term 'freehold' and 'freeholder' is in everyday use.

I know the question of 'freehold' has come up on this site before in discussion about 'condominium'. But that does not answer my question.

The origin of the term goes back the centuries-ago feudal system, and indicated land held as a free man, as opposed to a villein.

But 'freehold' today means the absolute rights of ownership, free of any lease, in a piece of land. The alternative to freehold is 'leasehold' where rights are held for a period of time according to the terms of a lease.

Comment: It is not in general use in American English; COCA's 146 results are almost entirely related to the township of Freehold in New Jersey. The NOLO law dictionary states it is "an antiquated term," so it may not be common in legal use, either.

Comment: @choster It is certainly an 'antiquated' term. It was used in the 14th century. But so were many other words we use today.

Comment: I've seen it on billboards advertising flats in Singapore, FWIW.

Comment: @choster In New Jersey, it is certainly used outside the context of the township name...it's what they call the county legislators. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Board_of_chosen_freeholders

Comment: @JeffSahol Those are freehold*ers*.

Comment: So far only Singapore has been mentioned. What about Canada, Australia, etc?

Answer (score 1):

In the US, we say ["fee simple"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fee_simple).

Comment: That means very much the same thing.

Comment: In the UK, _fee simple_ sounds like something out of mediaeval history, whereas _freehold_ is in normal legal use (at least in England and Wales: I think it is in use in Scotland, but I'm not sure).

Comment: In my life, I've bought, oh, six houses in the US, all of them "fee simple" (which according to Wikipedia is a freehold) and don't tell my wife but all of them _homme seul._

Comment: @ColinFine  'Fee simple' is an English common law term relating to the way that land is owned. Wikipaedia gives you the full history of it. It is based on the notion that the Crown has 'radical title' or 'allodium' i.e. that the Crown actually owns everything, and the person we generally regard as the owner is granted a 'freehold'. I feel sure it is the prevailing system of land law in all common-law countries, including the United States. But try telling Americans (who are not land-law experts) that the British Crown holds 'radical title' to all the land from the Atlantic to the Pacific!

Answer (score 1):

In Australia, the term *freehold* is still used. However, it is more likely that the type of freehold title is actually mentioned: [torrens and strata](http://www.echoice.com.au/buying-a-home/types-title/) most commonly.

One of the most common uses of the word *freehold* that I can think of in Australia is usually in discussions surrounding [native title](http://www.comlaw.gov.au/Details/C2011C00545) claims, and recognition of land rights of Aboriginal and Torres Strait Islander people.

On the other hand, I don't think the term *freeholder* is used, other than describing long-lost ancestors.